# Crack zip file with parts of passwords known

Tags: password, zip

I have a *zip* file that I can't open since I forgot the password. I'm pretty sure of some parts of this password but I can't remember the variations I added to it. I tried [fcrackzip](http://cvs.schmorp.de/fcrackzip/fcrackzip.html) but I can't see how to signify that I know parts of the password. To summarize:

- I know some parts of the password, example "*hello*", "*world*" and "*shittypass*".
- These parts can be in any order and not all of them may be used.
- Some additional small parts may appear, like 3 to 5 lower case letters.

Do you know any software that can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline of method:

1. Use a util like [`crunch`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crunch-wordlist/) to create a custom dictionary file.
2. Run `fcrackzip` with that custom dictionary.

Problems:

- Up to 3 strings mixed with anywhere from 3-5 lower case letters makes upwards of a trillion possible passwords.  Just generating that dictionary will take a while.
- `crunch` permits using character-based wildcards, but its handling of custom strings is not as flexible.  To solve this Q, `grep`, `sed` and `sort` also seem to be needed, any of which increases the time needed, i.e. hours, maybe days...

Something like this would probably work:

```
crunch 3 9 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123 | \
  grep '[123]' | # at least one number per dict entry
  egrep -v '([123]).*\1' | # remove repeated numbers
  sed 's/1/hello/;s/2/world/;s/3/shittypass/' | # replace numbers with strings
  sort -u | \
  fcrackzip -D -p /dev/stdin foo.zip
```

---

Test case with a smaller problem set (one or two strings, and up to two lower-case letters, any order):

```
echo foo > bar.txt  # file to archive
zip -P xhellobworld baz bar.txt   # archive with password
time crunch 2 4 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12 | \
     grep '[12]' | egrep -v '([12]).*\1' | \
     sed 's/1/hello/;s/2/world/' | \
     sort -n | fcrackzip -u -D -p /dev/stdin baz.zip
```

Output:

```
Crunch will now generate the following amount of data: 3163440 bytes
3 MB
0 GB
0 TB
0 PB
Crunch will now generate the following number of lines: 637392 


PASSWORD FOUND!!!!: pw == xhellobworld

real    0m5.942s
user    0m2.240s
sys 0m1.040s
```

Comment: Awesome. My combination would be less computationally expensive since I'm almost sure the random characters are at the end. Thx you.